# MySQL Subquery - Returning More Than One Row

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a table in which there are a listing of names, first and last in a column. So a column, called "manager" could have a value of "John Doe". I want to right a query that simply goes through each row in this table and displays the first letter and last name of the "manager" column. Everything I do comes up with "Subquery returns more than one row".

Starting small, I've just decided to pull the first letter:

```
SELECT id, LEFT((SELECT manager FROM my_table), 1) FROM my_table;
```

Or am I just completely off base on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a subquery to fetch into a field of a parent query. As such, the subquery can return only a single row. think of it this way: a result set is a 2-dimensional construct. a series of columns and rows. The data a subquery returns has to match the physical constraints of the thing it's returning into.

Since you're fetching into a field, that means one SINGLE value. If multiple values were allowed to be returned, you'd effectively be trying to turn your 2D result set into a 3d set (rows + columns plus a skyscraper growing out of one of those fields).

Your query does NOT need to be a subquery at all:

```
SELECT id, LEFT(manager, 1) AS first_letter FROM yourtable
```

Also, not that if you want separate first and last names, you would be better off storing those are separate fields. It is very easy to rebuilt a name from a set of first/last name fields, but very very difficult to reliably separate a monolithic name into individual first and last names, e.g.

```
simple:
     John Doe   (fn: john, ln: doe)
hard:
     Billy Jo Todd (is that "Billy" and "Jo Todd", "Billy" and "Todd" with middle name Jo?

dead simple:

    field firstname = John
    field lastname = Doe
```

Comment: Dude this is fantastic. I don't know why I was making it harder than it should have been. This is a great answer! This is my query now:

SELECT DISTINCT sponsor, CONCAT(LEFT(sponsor, 1), SUBSTRING(sponsor, (LOCATE(" ", sponsor) + 1))) AS First_Character
FROM importReviewInfo;

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a subquery, this query works as you intend it to, though I am not sure this is the best way to proceed in any case. We would need more information about your needs to assert that.

```
SELECT 
  m1.id, 
  m2.manager

FROM 
  my_table AS m1 INNER JOIN
  (SELECT id, LEFT(manager, 1) AS manager FROM my_table) as m2
  ON m1.id = m2.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c395/6

Answer (score 0):

You must add a condition to your subquery to return the row you want to compare like

```
SELECT manager FROM my_table WHERE id = 1
```